# Using Case expression in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

There has been a case statement used in my solution which is not working as expected.
Can anyone please correct it?

I have a below given table

```
create table data_cte
(
weekdate datetime,
activity varchar(10),
starttime varchar(5),
endtime varchar(5),
duration numeric(6,2),
ishomeoroffice varchar(1),
ispaidgap varchar(1),
isScheduled varchar(1)
)
```

Data in it will be as below.

```
           weekdate         ||  activity    ||  starttime       ||  endtime         ||  duration    ||  ishomeoroff ||  ispaidgap   ||  isscheduled
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||   08:00          ||  11:00           ||  3           ||  H           ||  N           ||  Y
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||       GAP    ||  11:00           ||  12:00           ||  1           ||  G           ||  Y           ||  Y
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||  T-100002    ||   12:00          ||  13:00           ||  1           ||  H           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||   13:00          ||  15:00           ||  2           ||  O           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||  15:00           ||  18:00           ||  3           ||  O           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||  T-100002    ||  18:00           ||  18:45           ||  0.75        ||  O           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||       GAP    ||  18:45           ||  19:15           ||  0.5         ||  G           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-09 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||  19:15           ||  22:15           ||  3           ||  H           ||  N           ||  N
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||  8:15            ||  11:15           ||  3           ||  H           ||  N           ||  Y
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||       GAP    ||  11:15           ||  12:15           ||  1           ||  G           ||  Y           ||  Y
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||  T-100002    ||  12:15           ||  13:15           ||  1           ||  H           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||  13:15           ||  18:00           ||  4.75        ||  O           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||  T-100002    ||  18:00           ||  18:45           ||  0.75        ||  O           ||  N           ||  NULL
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||       GAP    ||  18:45           ||  19:30           ||  0.75        ||  G           ||  Y           ||  NULL
    2013-09-10 00:00:00.000 ||  W-100001    ||  19:30           ||  21:30           ||  2           ||  H           ||  N           ||  Y
```

I need one more column to mark the travel which has to be paid as 'Y'. Below are the conditions for marking it.

1. If a travel is after a paid gap, It should be marked as 'Y'
2. If Travel is before paid gap, It should be be marked as 'Y'
3. If the travel is after scheduled work. i.e. one work(scheduled) activity then paidgap(Y/N) then travel activity, that Travel should be be marked as 'Y'
4. If the travel is before any scheduled work, i.e  Travel then paidgap(Y/N) then work(scheduled), that Travel should be be marked as 'Y'

Making it simpler, If the travel happens for a purpose, i.e for any scheduled work, then the travel has to be marked 'Y' else 'N'.

I have tried the below one. But, its marking 'Y' for the Travel(9th sep , 18:45-19:15 ) which is actually wrong, because the purpose of travel was not scheduled (means, the subsequent work was not scheduled)

```
select weekdate,activity,starttime,endtime,duration,ishomeoroffice,ispaidgap,
(case when activity='T-100002' then 
(case 
when exists(select 1 from data_cte cd1 where T3.weekdate=cd1.weekdate and T3.endtime=cd1.starttime and cd1.activity='GAP' and cd1.ispaidgap='Y') then 'Y'
when exists(select 1 from data_cte cd2 where T3.weekdate=cd2.weekdate and T3.endtime=cd2.starttime and cd2.activity='W-100001'and cd2.isscheduled='Y') then 'Y'
when exists(select 1 from data_cte cd3 where T3.weekdate=cd3.weekdate and T3.starttime=cd3.endtime and cd3.activity='GAP' and cd3.ispaidgap='Y')then 'Y'
when exists(select 1 from data_cte cd4 where T3.weekdate=cd4.weekdate and T3.starttime=cd4.endtime and cd4.activity='W-100001'and cd4.isscheduled='Y') then 'Y'

else 'N' end) 
end)
isTravel,
isScheduled from data_cte T3 ORDER BY weekdate,starttime
```

Can anyone please suggest me a way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I just saw your query with case .. I think you can change that by combining these multiple conditions 
`select 1 from data_cte cd1 where T3.endtime=cd1.starttime and cd1.activity='GAP' and cd1.ispaidgap='Y'`
`select 1 from data_cte cd2 where T3.endtime=cd2.starttime and cd2.activity='W-100001'and cd2.isscheduled='Y'`
when exists(select 1 from data_cte cd3 where T3.starttime=cd3.endtime and cd3.activity='GAP' and cd3.ispaidgap='Y')then 'Y'
when exists(select 1 from data_cte cd4 where T3.starttime=cd4.endtime and cd4.activity='W-100001'and cd4.isscheduled='Y'

Comment: @pratikgarg :  I tried coupling those 4 conditions in to 2. It was the same result I ended up with.

Comment: just got this observation .. this is not solution . .

for better performance and understanding you can change your query by combining these four conditions .. 

select 1 from data_cte cd1 where (T3.endtime=cd1.starttime and cd1.activity='GAP' and cd1.ispaidgap='Y') or (T3.endtime=cd2.starttime and cd2.activity='W-100001'and cd2.isscheduled='Y')  .......

Comment: @pratikgarg : I agree. I just made it to simplify the scenario.

Comment: One more thing sir .. where is the entry for 18:44-19:15?? are you referring seventh row 18:45-19:15 in your question?

Comment: Side note: `CASE` is neither a clause (title) nor a statement (first sentence). It's an expression.

Comment: @PavanKumar .. Can you please update question with the result of your new query?

Comment: @pratikgarg : Hi, after imposing the condition on weekdates, Its giving the expected result. Will check more on it and get back to you.

Comment: @pratikgarg : Hi, There is one scenario where I might need your assistance. If, the scheduled work is after an unpaid gap, it should marking istravel as 'Y'... But, in this case, its not doing what i expect.

Comment: @pratikgarg : Refer my comments below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think .. You should have condition on `weekdate` columns also in your case statements.

check in your table there should be somewhere at least one row with `activity` value either "GAP" or "W-100001" with `ispaidgap` = "Y" along with either  `starttime` as '19:15' or `endtime` = '18:44'

Comment: I will impose condition on weekdate. But, in the current scenario, Both the gap and work lies in the same weekdate.

Comment: Hi, There is one scenario where I might need your assistance. If, the scheduled work is after an unpaid gap, it should marking istravel as 'Y'... But, in this case, its not doing what i expect.

Comment: consider an activity w-100001 from 7:30 to 8:30 then gap(unpaid='N') from 8:30 to 10:00. next travel should be paid in this case. Since, I'm using `(activity='GAP' and isgappaid='Y')` in the condition, Its not accounting the subsequent travel. Can you suggest me any tweak in the logic, I have written?

Comment: @PavanKumar sorry sir.. but I am not getting entries for  7:30 to 8:30 and  8:30 to 10:00.
can you please point out those entries (or provide the sequence/line number)?

Comment: Hi, After going through various approaches to solve this, I could not find anything valid to suffice all my requirements... Also, This could be done with a multidimensional array approach, which is quiet difficult in sql server. So, I am using a different technology altogether to solve this.

Comment: @PavanKumar well.. best of luck .. you can update me with new approach just to increase my knowledge ..